# Apache Case insentive URLs

Tags: apache, url, case-sensitive

Apache is not allowing me to access a link with a wrong case. This URL case sensitivity really sucks me. Can anyone help me out how to configure my apache so that however I call my URL it has to work.

I am running my site on a shared linux server and not provided with SSH. I tried all the solutions in google but nothing worked for me. Anybody please help me. Please do not tell me to get into so and so option (as there are limited services provided in my cPanel, find them in the below screenshot).

[image]

Comment: Related: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/13517625/i-want-my-site-to-have-case-in-sensitive-url