# I want my site to have "case in-sensitive" url

Tags: linux, .htaccess, url, case-insensitive

how to make url case in-sensitive
`www.mysite.com/Boss/ => Works`
but
`www.mysite.com/boss/ => not working

www.mysite.com/BOSS/ => not working

www.mysite.com/boSS/ => not working`
is there any way to do this using htaccess or any other way.
the server is running on linux.
mod_speling is disabled

Comment: Related: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/13475379/apache-case-insentive-urls

Answer (score 0):

You should enable mod_speling

```
CheckSpelling On
```

[Source and reference](http://answers.oreilly.com/topic/108-how-to-permit-case-insensitive-urls-with-apache/)

Comment: I am on a shared server so i dont have access to any of **conf** files